# I can't find geotag and import photos plugin (QGIS plugin)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2.8

I am doing a project on mapping tourist attractions and would like to attach photos and videos to point locations. I have read about the Geotag and Import Photos plugin but I can't find it in my plugin lists. I am using QGIS 2.8.2 Wien and I have downloaded the exiftool already.

Comment: It looks, currently there is no plugin to link media files (photos) to csv file (with location data), and display geotagged photos in QGIS.

Answer (score 3):

It is still available in the [QGIS Python Plugins Repository](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/geotagphotos/), I can also see it in plugins list:

[image: Plugin]

You can download it manually from the link provided (go to the *Versions tab*), you should receive a .zip file. Decompress the contents of this to `C:/Users/You/.qgis2/python/plugins` and restart QGIS (if it is already loaded).

The plugin should now be installed, you may have to enable it by going back to the Plugins list in the toolbar (*Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins*).

Comment: Hey Joseph, thank you for your response, much appreciated. I was able to find it. I was not getting it initially because I had not activated the settings to be able to view experimental plugins. The geotag and import photos plugin is apparently. still on experiment.

Comment: @MetrineBwisa - Ahh, apologies for not including that! But glad you found it. You should accept the answer you posted (click the green-faded tick) to show that your question has a solution =)

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else has the same problem go to your plugin tab>> install and update plugins>>settings and activate view experimental plugin tab. Go back to>> Not installed plugins and search geotag and import photos plugin. 
You will be able to see it.
In short the problem was with my settings.